# Enable and disable html control with VBscript

Tags: html, vbscript

I want to disable this html control using VBscript.

```
<input type="image" id="Package4" src="images/paypal.png" name="Submit" width="147" height="47">
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You need to show some more detail and maybe some existing code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here at SO we're happy to help answer any specific questions you might have, and we usually do so very quickly. However, if you don't provide more information for us to go on, we won't be able to help. Please take a moment to specify your exact problem in a clear way, and you can expect an equally clear answer in return.

Comment: <input   type="image"  id="Package4" src="images/paypal.png" name="Submit" width="147" height="47"> disable this html control using vb script

Comment: @ram edit the question and add some details.....this info is already present in question

Comment: @dcrodjer, I added the information to the question after he posted his comment. 
@ram singh, dcrodjer is right, you should add new information to your question by editing it. Don't post new information in a comment.

Comment: sir i m new so i m sufring next time i will post question with full description...

Comment: @ram singh That's ok. We don't mean to be cruel to you, we're only trying to help you ask a question that will get you an answer. You can still save this question by editing it and adding more information to it.

Comment: do you mean that this the output from ASP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so assuming the logic for disabling the element is in your ASP, you can simply conditionally write the `disabled` attribute

```
<%  dim disableInput
    disableInput = true %>
  <input type="image" id="Package4" src="images/paypal.png" name="Submit" width="147" height="47" 
<% if disableInput then
       Response.Write "disabled=""disabled"""
   end if %>
>
```

input tag reference http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/input/